# Setting http_proxy for Chromium in shell

Tags: shell, ubuntu, proxy, chromium

In order to set proxy in Chromium browser, one needs to go to

> Settings → Under the Hood → Change Proxy Settings → Network Proxy.

It's too complicated. How do I set http_proxy in shell? I've tried

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Also, if you only want to set the proxy on the Chromium browser -- not your entire network -- the command line is the only way to set the proxy just for the browser.  How can one set the proxy on Chromium -- using the command line -- to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to use command line?

Comment: Do you only want to have the proxy for Chromium, or do you want one system-wide?  That is, every application that connects to the Internet would be forced through this proxy.

Comment: I edited the question to demonstrate another problem. The Chromium GUI only changes the proxy for the **entire network** not just the browser. The command line allows one to override this. Thus, this question may be useful on Super User, if it can be migrated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the `--proxy-server` argument.

From the [Chromium Network Settings](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings) page:

`--proxy-server=<scheme>=<uri>[:<port>];.. | <uri>[:<port>] | "direct://"`
This tells Chrome to use a custom proxy configuration. You can specify a custom proxy configuration in three ways:

1) By providing a semi-colon-separated mapping of list scheme to url/port pairs.
   For example, you can specify:
     `--proxy-server="http=foopy:80;ftp=foopy2"`
   to use HTTP proxy "foopy:80" for http URLs and HTTP proxy "foopy2:80" for ftp URLs.

2) By providing a single uri with optional port to use for all URLs.
   For example:
    `--proxy-server="foopy:8080"`
   will use the proxy at foopy:8080 for all traffic.

3) By using the special "direct://" value.
   `--proxy-server="direct://"`
   will cause all connections to not use a proxy.

---

You can also have a look at this [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: beat me to it 54 seconds.